# Use AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter for multiple URLs

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the below endpoint patterns in my application

1. /token -- accessible to all
2. /rest/securedone/** -- requires authentication
3. /rest/securedtwo/** -- requires authentication
4. /rest/unsecured/** -- does not require authentication

As of now, I am able to access the /token endpoint.
But /rest/securedone/** and /rest/unsecured/** return 401 when a token(JWT) is not sent. It is my intention to secure /rest/securedone/** and that is fine /rest/unsecured/** should be accessible.

My httpSecurity config is as below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/secured/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http.headers().cacheControl();
}
```

and my AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter extended class is as below:

```java
public class MyAuthenticationTokenFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAuthenticationTokenFilter.class);

    public MyAuthenticationTokenFilter() { super("/rest/**");  }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, ServletException {
        //authentication handling code
    }


    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Can someone please help my figure out the below:

1. When is the MyAuthenticationTokenFilter used? For which URL will it be invoked? How come, `/rest/unsecured/**` is also expecting authentication? It happens even if i explicitly say `.antMatchers("/rest/secured/**").permitAll()`.
2. Can I specify multiple url patterns in my `super(defaultFilterProcessingUrl)` call inside `MyAuthenticationTokenFilter` constructor? For example, if I have another url such as `/api/secured/**`, how can I get my `MyAuthenticationTokenFilter` to be invoked for `/api/secured/**` requests? I do not need different authentication handling so I want to re-use this filter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> When is the MyAuthenticationTokenFilter used ?

This filter is using for processing the request with client credential,it will filter the url when the 
`RequestMatcher` match the request url, for example, in your configuration, it will handle the url that matches `/rest/**`, and try to convert the client credential to `Authentication`(e.g userInfo, role ...), it maybe throws an exception when the request with incorrect client credential.
It is different to `authorizeRequests`(`xxx.authenticated()` or `xxx.permit()`), `authorizeRequests` just check the whether the authentication has some special attributes (e.g role, scope).

By way of analogy, `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` just puts some cards(`Authentication`) into a box(`SecurityContext`) by different clients, `authorizeRequests` just check the box has the card that it needed, or it will deny the request. `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`
 don't care who/how to use the cards, and `authorizeRequests` don't care where the cards come from.

> Can I specify multiple url patterns in my super(defaultFilterProcessingUrl) call inside MyAuthenticationTokenFilter constructor ?

Yes, you can set the `requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher` by `setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher`, it will override the old `requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher`, for example,

```
authenticationTokenFilter
    .setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new OrRequestMatcher(                                                                                     
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/rest/secured/**")                                                                                   
        , new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/secured/**")                                                                            
     ));
```

Comment: thanks a ton for the simplified explanation and your time. I think I have a more solidified understanding of it now.